# Display tooltip on mouseEntered event

Tags: java, cursor, tooltip, mouseevent

Java: I have a little app that uses an IconImage. It is set, in the Swing palette properties to display a Hand_Cursor when hovered and a tooltip. The hand cursor displays on hover whether the app has focus or not. But, the tool tip only displays when the app has focus. How do I make the behavior of the tool tip match that of the cursor?

Comment: Providing some codes will get you a quick answer...

Comment: Since posting this question, I've implemented the Nimbus look and feel. When I did that the erratic tool tip behavior went away. The tool tip now displays (with a brief lag) whenever the hand cursor displays (on hover). The little app can be found: http://maxw3st.us/tradingClock/tradingClock.html There's a link to download the NetBeans project folder (which contains a dist folder with the .jar file).

Comment: so the problem is solved now ?? if not i will upvote your question so others can help you.., btw cool app ..